# Type conversion error in VB when accessing a HTML table

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

I have a HTML table where I am allowing dynamic adding/deleting rows (that contain text-input's in the cells) using some JavaScript. I am not using ASP.NET TextBox controls, just traditional HTML, as I don't think rows containing ASP.NET controls can be added/deleted without a postback.

When the user clicks an ASP:Button, I am using VB to loop through the table rows in server-code, and ultimately use LINQ to write to a database. I have "Imports System.Web.UI.HtmlControls" in the file.

The code where I am getting problems is:

```
Dim name As HtmlInputText

name = row.Cells(0).Controls(0)
```

The error is: "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.LiteralControl' to type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText'." On the 2nd line above.

There is only one input control in each cell, so I am assuming I can use "Controls(0)" to access it. I have read solutions that use "FindControl", but I don't think this works with standard HTML "inputs", but also, as the rows are dynamically added/deleted, it's near-impossible to know the "ID" to search for.

Any ideas? Cheers.

Comment: I would assume that your cell has some literal text as well as the input box - even if this is just whitespace. Debug. Check what `row.Cells(0).Controls` actually contains and then code  as appropriate.

Comment: The cell does not contain any thing except the input, ie:
    <td class="SetBorder" style="text-align:center"><input type="text" id="txtName1" maxlength="50" size="20" /></td>

Comment: It clearly at least has a `LiteralControl` in it at the first position so I'm not sure I believe you when you say that it doesn't contain anything except the input. Have you actually debugged and looked at the Controls collection or are you just assuming?

Comment: Well I tried deleting all carriage returns and blank space, so the tr and /tr are all on one big line. Still getting the problem. Not sure how to check the controls collection off the top of my head.

Comment: Do you know how to debug things? If not go and learn how to debug straight away! You should be able to stop your code on that line and look at the values. Teaching you how to do it is a bit big for a comment but I'm sure there are plenty of tutorials out there.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into it and post again if I am still getting issues

Comment: Learning how to debug is the most valuable skill you can learn as a programmer. Good luck with it!

Comment: Have your table generated dynamically from code-behind or client-side code (with `<table runat="server">` or `asp:Table`)? `FindControl` only works for server controls (literal controls doesn't work), I suggest you show table structure to clarify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the problem. Just needed to add runat="server" to the input tags. Thanks every one for the replies.